# Why isn't the .AspNet.ApplicationCookie Secure / SameSite set to Strict by default?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Why doesn't the identity cookie (`.AspNet.ApplicationCookie`) set by asp.net mvc framework which authenticates the user set to have `SameSite` to `strict` or `Secure` set to `true` by default?
Doesn't this make it easier for a maliscious hacker to steal your cookie?